# How to mention the FileInputFormat in readFile method of flink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using flink to read the data continuously from the file which gets append with data regularly. I tried to use readFile method in flink.But confused with how to mention the FileInputFormat in the argument of this method. My file format is json. Could anyone help me with this?.Thanks

Comment: readFile(new CustomInputFormat(),"filePath"). Your custom input format can extend TextInputFormat or any existing InputFormat class to take advantage of code reuse .

Answer (score 2):

Flink's InputFormat's are not suited to read from files which are concurrently written to.

Given this requirement, I assume you are looking for a way to consume the file as a stream and process it with Flink's DataStream API. In that case, you would need to implement a SourceFunction that tracks the size and progress of the file and continuously reads the file.

However, I would not recommend this design. I'd rather periodically start a new file and move it to a dedicated folder for consumption once it has been finalized and the next file been started.